# Cast Error Mongodb Nodejs

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb

Good afternoon, 
  I am getting a Cast Error from my Nodejs backend while I am requesting from my Android App. To be clear, first request from my app works well, but the second request causes a Cast Error. Apart from that, I dont get any error when I use Postman, no matter how many requests I fire.

- Backend Code Nodejs and Mongoose

  ```
    app.post('/adsclicked/:id', function (req, res) {
        Ad.findOne({_id : req.params.id}, function (err, data) {   
            if (err) console.log(err);
            var new_clicked_count = data.clicked + 1;  //Updating count

            data.set({ clicked: new_clicked_count });  //Saving new count
            data.save(function (err, updatedData) {
                if (err) console.log(err);

                res.send(updatedData);   //Indicate new object
            });
        });

    });
  ```
- Android App

  ```
  public void AdVisitCount(Context context, String id){
  Log.d("advisit id", id);
  RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
  URL_FOR_ADVISITCOUNT = URL_FOR_ADVISITCOUNT + id;
  StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
          URL_FOR_ADVISITCOUNT, new Response.Listener<String>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(String response) {
          Log.d(TAG, "advisitcount Response: " + response.toString());
      }
  }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
      }
  });
  // Adding request to request queue
  queue.add(strReq);
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the data type of updatedData in nodejs

```
console.log(typeof(updatedData));
```

See if it is a object or a string

Comment: Oh my.. I am such a fool. I was adding “id” to Url with every request. On second it was url +id+id and so on....

Answer (score 0):

Problem is adding “id” to Url with every request. On second it was url +id+id and so on....

Delete the URL = URL + id;
line and add the query parameter id inside the request:

[...].POST, URL+id, new Response.Listener[...]